# Set value of columns to 0 based on priority?

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like the below:

| ID | Valid | Expired | NA | WIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I have a requirement to build some code which based on the column name, sets only one column to 1, based on the priority of the columns. The priority is as follows:

- VALID
- EXPIRED
- NA
- WIP

So if anything has a Valid flag of 1, everything else should show as 0. If Valid is 0, then it should move down the priority and check if the Expired column is 1; if it is then everything else should show as 0, and so on... like below:

| ID | Valid | Expired | NA | WIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I have actually achieved this already, but it's a bit of a hefty case statement (case when valid = 1 then 0, case when valid = 0 and expired = 1...)

Does anyone else have any better approaches to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use `case` expression:

```
select
    id,
    valid,
    case when valid                > 0 then 0 else expired end expired,
    case when valid + expired      > 0 then 0 else na      end na,
    case when valid + expired + na > 0 then 0 else wip     end wip
from t
```